# Sqlite does not detect unique key on a table despite primary key being present

Tags: sqlite, dbeaver, sqlitejdbc

I am trying to remove a record from `sqlite` database. I use `dbeaver` program for all operations. So when the action is performed, following error is shown:

[image]

[image]

The error says that unique key is not present. Query for table creation was this:

```
CREATE TABLE betGroups ( 
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
betgroupstatus INTEGER NOT NULL,
dateInserted DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

However, If we check the unique keys tab - we will see that a unique key is present:

[image]
[image]

So basically, `primary key` IS considered a `unique key`. Nevertheless an error is still shown.

Is there a good explanation why I am getting this error? I tried adding a `UNIQUE` keyword for an `id` field. table was created, but it made no difference.. Is there anything else I can change either in program options or in SQL script in order for the error to go away.

I am not sure if this is my script issue, a driver issue, or a program issue.

Using:

- org.sqlite.JDBC 3.28.0
- dbeaver 6.1.1

Comment: Show how you're trying to delete rows?

Comment: Selecting a row and pressing DELETE button on a keyboard. Then, on the bottom of the page you will see a `save` button (along with `cancel`).

Comment: So you're not manually entering a delete statement? It's an issue with that tool, then, not sqlite.

Comment: @Shawn or my creation query is simply broken? But the comment is still valid..  The issue could be related to either. So I filed a bug to dbeaver as well. Let's see who responds faster :) https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/6337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up to be a defect in `DBeaver`. Quote:

https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/6337

> This is side effect of the #424 fix. Currently DBeaver doesn't use
>   unique keys with nullable columns. I believe we should use them in
>   SQLite at least.

Comment: @halfer do you think that I need to remove the question or is it fine to keep it?